# add a new named key into matches of the preg_match_all

Tags: php, key, preg-match-all

My original code is:

```
$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);

$all_matches = $matches1[0];

foreach ($all_matches as $match)
{
   $sid = '9';

   $rov['batch'] = $match;
   $rov['scid'] = $sid;
   $res[] = $rov;
}

print_r($res);
```

How can i add a new named key ['type'] into $matches1 of the preg_match_all to call it inside foreach and give me the final output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [batch] => 8491241
            [type] => 1
            [scid] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [batch] => 568241
            [type] => 1
            [scid] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [batch] => 6254841
            [type] => 1
            [scid] => 9
        )
)
```

what i tried is:

```
$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);

$pr_matches1['batch'] = $matches1[0];
$pr_matches1['type'] = 1;
$all_matches[] = $pr_matches1;

foreach ($all_matches as $match)
{
   $sid = '9';

   $rov['batch'] = $match['batch'];
   $rov['type'] = $match['type'];
   $rov['scid'] = $sid;
   $res[] = $rov;
}

print_r($res);
```

But it give me wrong output
http://pastebin.com/WXGpLTX9

Any idea please?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you show us what your attempt does, rather than just saying it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to "extend" each matched item:

```
$all_matches = array_map(function($match) {
    return [
      'batch' => $match,
      'type' => 1,
      'scid' => 9,
    ];
}, $matches1[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);

$all_matches = $matches1[0];

foreach ($all_matches as $match)
{
   $rov['batch'] = $match;
   $rov['type'] = 1;
   $rov['scid'] = 9;
   $res[] = $rov;

}

print_r($res);

?>
```

Comment: no, in my case, i need a new named key ['type'] into $matches1 of the preg_match_all..please take a moment to read my question again, thank you.

Comment: but this code give you the same output that you need, why you want modify $matches1 ?